# Access dynamic to json from html

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm using angular translate with:

```
<script src="lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
```

with a JSON file for english dict as:

```
{
  "test": "test_en",
  "menu": {
    "home": "home",
    "config": "settings",
    "logout": "log out"
  }
}
```

now I have function (ng-repeat) that dynamically writes my side menu, but I'm having problems to get the name of the JSON file.

if I use:

```
<span class="menuname">{{"test" | translate}}</span>
```

the output is correct : test_en

but how do I access to menu.home for example?

the menu name or struct is called element, and if I use

```
<span class="menuname">{{element.menuname}}</span>
```

I get, home, config,... so I'm looking for something like:

```
<span class="menuname">{{"test.[element.pagename]" | translate}}</span>
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content></ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-content>
            <div class="list-group" ng-controller="ListMenuItems as ItemList ">
                <div ng-repeat="element in ItemList.menuitems" >
                    <a class="item padding_0" menu-close ng-href="{{element.sref}}" ng-class="navClass('{{element.pagename}}')">
                        <div class="centered">
                            <img ng-src="{{element.img2show}}" />
                            <span class="menuname">{{"menu.[element.pagename]" | translate}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

in app.js

```
var App = angular.module('MyApp.controllers')

App.controller('ListMenuItems',['$scope','$location',
    function($scope,$location){
        this.menuitems = menuitems;
        $scope.navClass = function (page) {
            var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(5) || 'home';
            //console.log(page ," ::: ", currentRoute);
            return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : 'no_active';
        };
}]);

var menuitems = [
    {
        menuname: 'home',
        pagename: 'home',
        sref: '#/app/home',
        img2show: "img/menu/iconos/home.png",
    },
    {
        menuname: 'configuració',
        pagename: 'settings',
        sref: "#/app/settings",
        img2show: "img/menu/iconos/settings.png",
    },
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a full code as an exapmle.

Otherwise, I would assume that you dont use ng-repeat before span.

You should use:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in JSONs">
<span class="menuname">{{item.item | translate}}</span>
<span class="menuname">{{item.menu | translate}}</span>
<span class="menuname">{{item.menu.home | translate}}</span>
<span class="menuname">{{item.menu.config | translate}}</span>
<span class="menuname">{{item.menu.logout | translate}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I though It was enough code for explain my question. I've added the main structure of the side menu. Thanks